# How to configure GPIO pins as digital outputs on LTC6804?

Tags: batteries, multiplexer, gpio

Can someone explain how to configure GPIOs as digital output pins on LTC6804. I have a MUX whose inputs are connected on GPIO2 - GPIO4 and the output is connected to GPIO1. My task is to control MUX inputs so I can read various voltages on the output but the problem is that I can't find in the datasheet how to configure those GPIOs as digital output pins.

Answer (score 1):

This is done by appropriately setting the bits of the CFGR0 register (see table 36): The five upper bits (named GPIOx) are used to configure these pins. If you write a 0 in them, the correspondig GPIO pin will be actively driven low. If you write 1 (default value), it will be in high-impedance state (see table 46).

These PINs are open-drain (see page 31). So, if you want to use them as output, you need an external pull-up.

Comment: I've done it but GPIOs are still high. I also use pullup resistors.

Comment: tell me what is your pullup value.